# cryptoapi delphi Rsa генерация и экпорт ключей

Tags: delphi, cryptoapi

пытаюсь сгенерировать  ключи и экспортировать их, но чтот не особо получается, можете подсказать, что я делаю не так ?
вот так генерирую :

```
    var
  Prov: HCRYPTPROV;
  ExchangeKey, SignKey: HCRYPTKEY;
begin
  CryptAcquireContext(@Prov,'My_Container',nil,PROV_RSA_FULL,CRYPT_NEWKEYSET);
   CryptGenKey(Prov,AT_KEYEXCHANGE,0,@ExchangeKey);
  CryptGenKey(Prov,AT_SIGNATURE,0,@SignKey);
 CryptDestroyKey(SignKey);
  CryptDestroyKey(ExchangeKey);
  CryptReleaseContext(Prov,0);
```

и экспортирую

```
var
  Prov: HCRYPTPROV;
  SignKey: HCRYPTKEY;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  BufSize: DWORD;

  ExchangeKey: HCRYPTKEY;
begin

  CryptAcquireContext(@Prov,'My_Container',nil,PROV_RSA_FULL,0);
  CryptGetUserKey(Prov,AT_SIGNATURE,@SignKey);
  Stream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  CryptExportKey(SignKey,0,PUBLICKEYBLOB,0,nil,@BufSize);
  Stream.SetSize(BufSize);
  CryptExportKey(SignKey,0,PUBLICKEYBLOB,0,PByte(Stream.Memory),@BufSize);
  Stream.SaveToFile('fiile.txt');
  Stream.Free;
  CryptDestroyKey(SignKey);
  CryptReleaseContext(Prov,0);

end;
```

но в результате получаю

> $  RSA1     ™Ї4ЁI“,¤·њПЂџкјѓИ¦ &€moг»4„·иљьz\Iq†ЂKхЯтZpШя·n
>   _Зo/]n\h)­#‘ P3ВхќљёQ `ыТuыј–Ш“НЗ3еЪ~F9zкѕr©АrР™ж‚Ыт‰™rю¤дў*а

не особо похоже на ключ, да и он всегда одинаковый, можете тыкнуть носом, что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Не так - вы не проверяете статус возврата из API. "не особо похоже на ключ" это вы так считаете, на самом деле это похоже на блоб публичного ключа.

Comment: можете помочь исправить ?

Comment: Я не пишу и не буду писать на Delphi

Comment: Дополните вопрос - в каком формате вы хотите получить публичный ключ. Ну и - помимо замечания Владимира Мартьянова о не-проверке статуса возврата функций - вы же уничтожаете ключ до его использования....